# Where will the Initialized data segment values are stored before run time?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Normally the data segment in *C code* resides in the *RAM* volatile memory and consists of Initialized data segment, *Uninitialized data segment(.BSS)*, *Stack memory* and the heap.

1. Stack memory is only coming to picture while on run time call routines and in *push* and *pull* of values.
2. Heap is used on dynamic memory allocation calls `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`.
3. *.BSS segment* is only having value by memset or inside functions as it doesnot have any genuine initial values .
4. But the *Initialized data segment* even though it is static or global must be having some values and these values needs to be stored in a non volatile memory location as it should exist before the running of the code.

**Question:**
In which section of non volatile memory location this initialized values are stored and whether any means we can use to reduce the memory consumption of this?

Comment: Initialised data is not stored in non volatile memory while the process is running but it goes along with rest of segments in RAM.

Comment: If controller is switched off and powered on who will have this data then to be loaded to RAM memory?

Comment: When process is loaded from non volatile memory like hard disk executable file initialised data will come along with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following two diagrams helps to understand the memory layout of c binary

[image]
[image]

Refer : [C compiler. Memory map. Program](https://www.ele.uva.es/%7Ejesus/hardware_empotrado/Compiler.pdf)

Comment: Are you mentioning that there will be an initialized data segment block in the flash as you mentioned in .data and it will be copied to the RAM by the boot loader.

Comment: Yes.. Disable any binary.. you will see above structure i.e .text, .data, .bss, .rodata etc.

Comment: I hope the bss is not required and in your diagram also it is not mentioned. Everywhere the rodata constant is mentioned but i got confused with this.Thank you so much for the info.

Comment: Is this a general one or applicable for the ARM processor only? What about the controllers where the entire memory is continuous means the code section as well as the data segment? Is it better in code to make this data segment to be initialized on run time so that the memory can be saved from the ROM as this become a redundant block?

Comment: There is no "general one" as each architecture has it's own memory organization. The C standard doesn't introduce what is "stack" and "heap" - and a perfecltly valid implementation may implement a `malloc` that uses "heap". Your question is very very very architecture dependent. There are harvard and newman architectures and C code runs on them all.

Comment: This is for ARM, others will defer based their architecture & compiler definition

Comment: Hello @KamilCuk As explained by you could you please make it clear how it will work in the other case , i mean the Von Neumann architecture. Or whether it will depend upon each controller other than these two memory architectures.

Comment: At number 2 image. I can find .rodata is removed. It is not a mistake?