# Is memory associated with a char *foo() function freed (in C)?

Tags: c

If I have a function return a pointer to a string, something like below (maybe different sytnax), is that string freed from memory at the end of the calling function `foo`?

```
void foo(){
    char *string = function();
    // Is string freed at the end of this function?
}

char *function(){
    return "string";
}
```

I'm asking this because I understand that if I were to `malloc()` the memory, it would not be freed at the end of `foo` (unless I go and free it myself).

Comment: It's a static string. It's never freed, because it was never allocated in the first place (or more precisely, it was allocated once, at the beginning of the program during program load, and lives until the program exits).

Comment: Okay thanks. Would this be considered bad practice? This would be regarding a function that needs to return only a handful of different strings, corresponding to a few different cases

Comment: If it's a small number of fixed strings, and you document the function as not requiring them to be freed, it's fine.

Comment: Not at all. For instance, this is exactly what `strerror` does (to first order). What's bad is if you *sometimes* return a static string and *other times* a malloced string, because then the caller has no way to tell if it needs to call free.

Comment: You'll need to express what the contract is where when calling `function`. Are you expected to free the memory? Is that not your problem? If it's left ambiguous, you get memory leaks. Remember, in C memory management is *explicit*. Dynamically allocated memory is never released for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Memory for `"string"` is allocated for the duration of program execution.

The memory of a C program can be roughly categorized as...

- The code.
- Constants like `"string"` and `42`.
- Globals and static variables.
- Stack (`char foo[50]` or `int i` inside a function)
- Heap (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`)

Constants, globals, and statics are never deallocated.

The stack is deallocated when the function returns. This is why one should not return pointers to memory allocated on the stack. Simple values like `int` and `float` are fine because the value is copied.

```
// Don't do this, foo will be deallocated on return.
char *function(){
    char foo[10];
    strcpy(foo, "string");
    return foo;
}

// Don't do this either.
char *function(){
    char foo = 'f';
    return &foo;
}

// Nor this.
int *function(){
    int i = 42;
    return &i;
}

// But this is fine.
char function(){
    char foo = 'f';
    return foo;
}
```

Heap is only deallocated when it is `free`d.

See [Where will the Initialized data segment values are stored before run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53942901/14660) and [Memory Layout of a C Program](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/) for the gory details.

Comment: Thanks, this and ShadowRanger's comment has cleared up my misunderstanding. I was wrongly thinking that `"string"` would exist on the stack or heap.

Comment: @SteadyState Where you can get into trouble is returning a pointer to writable static or global memory. That means each call to the function is using and returning the same memory. If two calls to the same function store the returned pointer, one will find it has been overwritten. Functions like `localtime`, `ctime`, and `strtok` do this. They are ["non-reentrant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) and have reentrant versions like `localtime_r` and `strtok_s`.

Comment: Whether string literals are stored in read-only memory is up to the C implementation. The C standard does not require it. Not all C implementations are for general-purpose multi-user systems with memory protection.

Comment: @SteadyState A good compiler will warn you if you're returning memory that will be deallocated. [Example](https://www.online-cpp.com/Z0lEnKWwFX). The problem is you have to turn these warnings on, and that gets complicated. `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` plus setting the C standard is a good start.

Comment: There is no need to introduce embedded systems. Simply do not make false statements. “`"string"` is stored in a read-only portion of the program's memory and is never freed.” can be changed to “Memory for `"string"` is allocated for the duration of program execution.”